# Best way to implement a collection of items for copying?

Tags: rust

I am writing my first program in Rust that takes a list of Cards and attempts to find the best deck from those cards.
I want to have a catalog of Cards that can be copied to decks. I'm trying to find an idiomatic way of doing this. My first thought was a vector or array containing one of every card and a function to return a copy of that card to a deck.

Here is my code:

```rust
pub trait Card {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &String;
    fn get_card_type(&self) -> &CardType;
    fn get_cost(&self) -> Option<&i32>;

    fn play(&self){
        println!("Played {} for {} mana.", self.get_name(), self.get_cost().unwrap());
    }
}

pub enum CardType {
    Creature,
    Spell,
    Land,
}

pub struct Creature {
    pub name: String,
    pub card_type: CardType,
    pub cost: i32,
    pub attack: i32,
    pub defense: i32,
    pub tapped: bool,
}

impl Card for Creature{
    fn get_name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }

    fn get_card_type(&self) -> &CardType {
        &self.card_type
    }

    fn get_cost(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        Some(&self.cost)
    }
}

pub struct Spell {
    pub name: String,
    pub card_type: CardType,
    pub cost: i32,
    pub damage: i32,
}

impl Card for Spell{
    fn get_name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }

    fn get_card_type(&self) -> &CardType {
        &self.card_type
    }

    fn get_cost(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        Some(&self.cost)
    }
}

pub struct Land {
    pub name: String,
    pub card_type: CardType,
    pub tapped: bool,
}

impl Card for Land{
    fn play(&self) {
        println!("Played {}.", self.get_name());
    }

    fn get_name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }

    fn get_card_type(&self) -> &CardType {
        &self.card_type
    }

    fn get_cost(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        None
    }
}

pub fn get_random_card() -> Box<Card> {
    Box::new( Creature{
        name: "My Card".to_string(), 
        card_type: CardType::Creature, 
        cost: 1, 
        attack: 2, 
        defense: 2,
        tapped: false,
    })
}
```

The get_random_card() function contains a sample card. So essentially I just need a static array or vector of cards and a function to copy them in to a deck, but I haven't been able to implement it. 
Any suggestions? Feel free to point out anything else I am doing wrong.

Edit: Some clarification -

The code here works, but I want a variable containing a list of available cards. For example

```
// some pseudocode, in file cards.rs
let cards = [
    Creature {
        name = "Creature 1"
        //...
    },
    Land {
        name = "Land 1"
        //...
    },
    Spell {
        name = "Spell 1"
        //...
    },
];

fn get_card(name) -> mut Card {
    // return a mutable copy/clone of a card, not a reference
}
```

And I would prefer to have it declared outside of the main function, in a separate file. I've tried several different things trying to make the compiler happy, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious. Memory isn't a big concern at the moment, there won't be that many cards in the "cards" var. But decks will be generated dynamically, so I need somewhere to get the cards in the deck from.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code compiles as-is [in the Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/), and you haven't provided any example code that shows what you want to do, what you have *already tried*, or any errors that prevent you from achieving your goal. We aren't mind readers. ^_^ At the very least, you should give us some pseudocode or function signatures to go on.

Comment: You wish to return a trait object (like `Box<Card>`), but *none of your trait methods* require mutability (they all take `&self`). How are you planning on mutating the objects?

Comment: I really don't need mutability at this point, it's more for the future, in case I need to implement more complicated cards. I might be misunderstanding &self though, I was thinking it was comparable to python's self.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't worried about allocating too much memory, you have everything you need right now:

```
fn main() {
    let hand: Vec<_> = (0..5).map(|_| get_random_card()).collect();
    for card in &hand {
        println!("{}", card.get_name());
    }
}
```

We simply grab 5 cards and store them in a `Vec`. We can then iterate over the vector and print out the card names.

If you are worried about memory and you are going to have a bunch of cards you want to "reuse", you could do as above and then take references to them:

```
fn main() {
    let deck: Vec<_> = (0..52).map(|_| get_random_card()).collect();

    let hand1 = &deck[0..5];
    let hand2 = &deck[5..10];
    let hand3 = &deck[10..15];
    let hand4 = &deck[15..20];

    for card in hand1 {
        println!("{}", card.get_name());
    }
}
```

Here, the compiler will prevent you from attempting to use a card after the deck goes out of scope. If you need more flexibility, you could use `Rc` in addition to `Box`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

pub fn get_random_card() -> Rc<Box<Card>> {
    Rc::new(Box::new(Creature {
        name: "My Card".to_string(), 
        card_type: CardType::Creature, 
        cost: 1, 
        attack: 2, 
        defense: 2,
        tapped: false,
    }))
}

fn main() {
    let deck: Vec<_> = (0..52).map(|_| get_random_card()).collect();

    let hand1 = deck[0..5].to_owned();
    let hand2 = deck[5..10].to_owned();
    let hand3 = deck[10..15].to_owned();
    let hand4 = deck[15..20].to_owned();

    for card in &hand1 {
        println!("{}", card.get_name());
    }
}
```

This lets each card manage a reference-count of active references. When the references go to 0, the card is freed.

**Note** In the Rust nightlies, you can use just `Rc<T>` instead of `Rc<Box<T>>`.

> Feel free to point out anything else I am doing wrong.

Three things stood out to me:

1. You should probably use `#[derive(Debug)]` on every struct. Other things to potentially derive are `Copy` and/or `Clone`, `PartialEq` and `Hash`. Of course, you can wait until you need one of those before adding it, but `Debug` is super useful right away.
2. Return `&str` instead of `&String`. 99.9% of the time, you want to use `&str` instead of `&String` — it's more flexible.
3. There's no reason to return references to small types like `CardType` or `i32` - just return them directly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at your suggestions now. I added more to my original question to clarify also. I need copies or clones or the cards, not references.